# How do I make Excel tab through merged cells in a protected sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am having a problem with how tab selection in an Excel sheet behaves on merged cells when the sheet is protected versus when it is unprotected.

I have a merged cell that is two rows high.  When the sheet is unprotected, the user is able to select either cell immediately to the left of the merged cells, hit tab once to enter the merged cell, and hit tab again to continue onto whatever row they started on.

[image: Unprotected Sheet Tab Behavior]

My issue is that when I protect the sheet, that behavior changes.  If the user selects the cell in the lower row and hits tab, their selection skips the merged cell entirely.

[image: Protected Sheet Tab Behavior]

I want the sheet to behave like it does when it is unprotected, even if I protect it.  What is causing the change in selection behavior, and what can I do to preserve the unprotected sheet behavior in a protected sheet?

I only see this behavior with hitting the tab key- the right and left arrow keys behave normally.

Comment: This can be added to the list of ways merged cells are annoying.

Comment: Not a fix, but you might be able to work around it by checking the `Select locked cells` in the `Protect Sheet` dialog box.  The protected cells are still locked so they can't change, but you can navigate to it.  OBTW, if you don't want anyone to see any formulas in the protected cells you will need to make them `Hidden` as well as `Locked`.

Comment: Why don't you upload GIF version of the Sheet for better understanding !!

Comment: @ReyJuna Thank you, unfortunately I've tried that and I still see the unwanted behavior.

Comment: I concur, I tried doing this in various ways and got different behaviors for the tab key.  It seems that MS chose to make the tab key bounce around to unlocked cells assuming that you would want to go to the next data entry point.  One thing that I found was that if the top cell is unlocked and the bottom one locked at the time that you merge them, you will get the behavior you describe.  If both of them are locked, it totally skips over it when protected.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this will not solve your problem either, but if it helps I avoid using merged cells altogether by removing vertical borders to give the appearance of merged and to "center across selection" to give the appearance in the horizontal.

I am aware this is just a work around, but hopefully it helps.